# Horizontal multiple select option in bootstrap 3 form

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently using the latest bootstrap framework and the 'select multiple' form element. As standard the options display one after the other vertically. I would prefer to display the options horizontally. Is there a way to do this? I have been looking at the CSS and can't figure out how I might be able to do this. Ideally I would like to take advantage of the grid system. My attempts to do this are not overriding the default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a hack that presents the styling I need whilst still giving the required form input. Instead of using a dropdown I have used a row of buttons that I can style as I wish. I can then use

```
onclick="this.form.label.value='0';
```

to pass the input back to a hidden form input.